# PHP MySQL & AJAX search filter time delay

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, search

This is the first time i am working on php and JavaScripts ... need your help in fixing something.

my site have a searchbox at the header, when a search term is submitted it goes to the search.php which holds a filter menu and search result. The filter menu is based on few selectlist. As soon as any optionis clicked in the filter menu it updates the search result.

For this i am using a javascript that calls data from another php file "SearchResult.php" to update a div with ID #Result.

PROBLEM:
it works perfectly fine at localhost however when online it causes a delay in updating the Search Result.

HELP:
Is there any way to show loading of some kind to let the viewer understand or is there anyway to make it fast.

here are my codes:

Java Script Function

```
function get() 
{
    $('#Search_Results').hide();
    $.post('SearchResults.php', { Search: form.Search.value, cat: form.category.value, brand: form.brand.value },
    function(output) 
        {
            $('#Search_Results').html(output).show();
        }
)
}
```

SEARCH FILTER FORM

```
enter code hereif(!empty($_REQUEST['Search'])){
$SearchTerm = $_REQUEST['Search'];
} else {
    $SearchTerm = '';
}
// Search term submited 
echo '<input name="Search" type="hidden" value="'.$SearchTerm.'" />';
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM categories");
echo '<h4>Filter Categories</h4><select name="cat" onChange="get();" size="15">';
echo '<option value="" class="Select_Options">All Categories</option>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
        {
            echo '<option class="Select_Options" value="' . $row["CategoryID"] . '">' . $row["CategoryName"] . '</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
//Few more such filters
```

---

SEARCH RESULT PAGE

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['Search'])){
$SearchTerm = $_REQUEST['Search'];
}
else {
echo 'Please enter search keyword(s)';
exit();
}
if(!empty($_REQUEST['cat'])){
$cat = $_REQUEST['cat'];
$SearchQuery .= " AND categories.CategoryID = '$cat'";
}

if(!empty($_REQUEST['brand'])){
$brand = $_REQUEST['brand'];
$SearchQuery .= " AND brands.BrandID = '$brand'";
}

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT products.ProductID, ProductKeywords, products.SectionID, products.ProductThumb, products.ProductPrice, products.CategoryID, products.SubCategoryID, products.BrandID, brands.BrandLogo, ProductTitle AS title FROM products 
    INNER JOIN brands ON products.BrandID = brands.BrandID 
    INNER JOIN sections ON products.SectionID = sections.SectionID 
    INNER JOIN categories ON products.CategoryID = categories.CategoryID 
    INNER JOIN subcategory ON products.SubCategoryID = subcategory.SubCatID $ColorJoin
    WHERE MATCH (ProductKeywords) AGAINST ('$SearchTerm*' in boolean mode)$SearchQuery";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
echo '<div id="Product_Search_Container"><ul>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{

    $ProductID = $row["ProductID"];     
    $sql2 = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(ProColorID) AS ProductCount FROM productcolors WHERE ProductID = '$ProductID'");     
            while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) 
            {
                $BrandID = $row["BrandID"];
                $sql3 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM brands WHERE BrandID = '$BrandID'");        
                while ($row6 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) 
                {
                    $ProductThumb = $row["ProductThumb"];
                    if ($ProductThumb == NULL) { $ProductThumb = "No_Image.jpg"; }

            echo '<li><img src="images/Products/Thumbs/' . $ProductThumb . '" width="210px" height="275px" />
                    <div class="zoomer"><span class="zoom';
                    if ($ProductThumb != "No_Image.jpg") {
                        echo ' cursonstyle" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"><img src="images/Products/Thumbs/zoom/' . $ProductThumb . '" alt="' . $row["title"] . '" />
                    '; } else { echo '">'; }
                    echo '</span><span class="Pro_Title">' . $row["title"] . '</span>
                    <span class="BrandLogo"><img src="images/Brands/' . $row6["BrandLogo"] . '" /></span>
                    <span class="ProColors">' . $row5["ProductCount"] . ' Colors</span>
                    <span class="ProPrice">$' . $row["ProductPrice"] . '</span>
                    <a href="?Product=' . $row["ProductID"] . '" class="viewdetails">&nbsp;</a></a></li>';  

                }                           
            }
}

        echo '</ul></div>';
```

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Also, please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: Try and narrow the problem down.  Is the query itself slow on the remote database?  Try running it directly using e.g. PHPMyadmin (if installed)?

Comment: thanks Eggyal, you are right ... i do need to secure the parameters and will start learning MySQLi right now. The query is fast on localhost but takes around 5-10 seconds on online test :(

Answer (score 1):

You could show a loading message as simple as showing it when you start the post request and hiding it in the callback.

```
function get() 
{
    $('#Search_Results').hide();
    $('#loading').show().html('Please wait while loading..'); // <-- show message on function call
    $.post('SearchResults.php', { Search: form.Search.value, cat: form.category.value, brand: form.brand.value },
    function(output) 
        {
            $('#loading').hide(); // <-- hide in callback function
            $('#Search_Results').html(output).show();
        }
)
}
```

You should also handle errors in your ajax request and look into prepared statements or at least use [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for all user inputs.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, the idea is nice but unfortunately the result is same..... the Loading Div is taking almost same time to appear :(

Comment: I thought you wanted to add a loading message. Maybe I got you wrong here: `Is there any way to show loading of some kind to let the viewer understand`. It's hard to say **why** it's slow, as already mentioned in the comments, the remote database could be slow or are you facing this problem only in this case? Have you tried running the query directly as @eggyal said?

Comment: The div with the message 'Please wait while loading' (from the jquery code) really needs 5-10s to appear?

Comment: yes unfortunately it do take 5-10s on online test:( ... i have no idea why .... maybe the execution of the function is what causing the delay ?

Comment: if also the loading message has this delay, your error may be in your javascript code. that's really weird.. can you post more of your js code or provide a live example (without mysql query because of your security issues)

Comment: well its a testing server so currently no security issues, here is the online testing link http://www.mentorarts.com/globalapparel/  .... try the search term "shirt" or "tshirt"

Comment: the search function is called on onkeyup="searchterm();" ... the triger is acting too slow ... you can see what i mean